# Reading string with exclamation mark includes a period

Tags: java, ms-access, jdbc, ucanaccess

I'm reading and writing from an mdb file* and doubling the exclamation marks to get a single exclamation mark (bang) into the database field.

```
aStringBuffer.append("'" + target.getTitle().replaceAll("!","!!") + "',");
```

The field above is used in an `insert into ...` statement successfully with the content starting out as `Sample!`, getting changed to `Sample!!` in the StringBuffer, and back to `Sample!` when I look at it in the table within the mdb.

Later, though, when I read the value using `rs = aStatement.executeQuery(...)`

then `rs.getString(aField)`, I get [`Sample.!`] instead of [`Sample!`].

Notice that there seems to be an unexpected "dot" or extra "period" in the result.

I'm wondering if this is a bug or if it's just something that I'm doing wrong.

*Windows 7, using ucanaccess version 2.0.9.4, JRE 1.8.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UCanAccess version 2.0.9.4 is ancient. This bug was [fixed in version 3.0.3.1](https://sourceforge.net/p/ucanaccess/discussion/help/thread/259caea6/#654e) over 3.5 years ago. Look [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/ucanaccess/files/) (or on Maven Central) to get the latest version.